# Google Apps Script Compare Active User to Array

Tags: google-apps-script

Not sure why this isn't working. I have a simple script that grabs the active user and checks to see if they are in an array of allowed senders. If they are, then it runs another function `sendEmail()`. If they are not in the array, then it throws an error.

```
function send(){
  var ValidEmailsArray = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com', 'email3@gmail.com']; //can be any number of emails.
  var ActiveUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  for (var i = 0; i < ValidEmailsArray.length; i++){
    if (ActiveUser.indexOf(ValidEmailsArray[i]) == -1) {
      throw new Error('Woah! You must send the email from the ' + ValidEmailsArray + ' account.');
    }
    else {
      sendEmail();
      return;
    }
  }
```

As it is now, it throws the error even if the ActiveUser is in the `ValidEmailsArray`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue:

`ActiveUser` is of type `string`.

```
if (ActiveUser.indexOf(ValidEmailsArray[i]) == -1) {throw new Error
```

says that if `ActiveUser` doesn't contain the first email address in `ValidEmailsArray`, throw a error.

#### Solution:

Use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of a loop.

#### Snippet:

```
function send(){
  const validEmailsArray = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com', 'email3@gmail.com']; //can be any number of emails.
  const activeUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  if(validEmailsArray.includes(activeUser)) sendEmail()
  else throw  new Error("?!")
}
```

Comment: @Marios Thanks 